# sudo . source_file command not found

Tags: bash, 22.04, sudo

```
. source_file
```

works.

```
sudo . source_file
```

doesn't work.

Is there a replacement command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`source` (and the alias `.`) is a builtin command, not an executable, therefore `sudo` doesn't work directly.

However, you could run:

```
sudo bash -c 'source /full/path/to/source_file'
```

This would start a bash session as root, and source `source_file` under this session. The file `source_file` could of course contain any number of commands that are run when it is sourced, but the shell would exit immediately this is done.

Another useful option would be to run a bash subshell with sudo, and source `source_file` as the initial commands. This can be done in a number of ways.

You could include `source_file` as the init file for bash:

```
sudo bash --init-file /full/path/to/source_file
```

This would source `source_file`, but on the other hand your `~/.bashrc` will NOT be sourced.

To get both the `~/.bashrc` and the `source_file`, we need to create a temporary init file that bash can use:

```
echo "source ~/.bashrc; source /full/path/to/source_file" > /dev/shm/initfile.rc; sudo bash --init-file /dev/shm/initfile.rc
```

With this command, bash sources both `~/.bashrc` and `source_file` in an interactive root shell (since it uses your newly created init file).

Comment: This is an exhaustive and sufficient answer.